# how can i time executing other function in concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor.map function?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a program where I am currently using a concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor to run multiple tasks concurrently. These tasks are typically I/O bound, invoking reading and printing output from a large text file and I need every minute to interrupt ThreadPoolExecutor and execute another function
I tried using the result method but it didn't work

```
def check_connection():
    try:
        request= requests.get("http://google.com",timeout=10)
        print("Connected to the internet")
        pass
    except(requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as exception:
        print("No internet connection waiting for connection")
        try:
            request= requests.get("http://google.com",timeout=10)
            print("Connected to the internet")
            pass
        except(requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as exception:
            input("please fix the internet issue to continue")
            
def printt(x):
    print(x)

def main():
    with open(passwd_wdlst, "r") as file:
        passwords = file.read().splitlines()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        try:
            executor.map(executor.map(printt,passwords)).result(timeout=60)
        except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
            print("cheking the internet connection")
            check_connection()
            continue
main()
```

how can I make it work or can I run the threadpool in timer to do that?

Comment: The code does not make much sense. 1. Nowhere do you invoke`check_connection`. 2. `map` does not return a `Future` on which you can call `result`. 3. Your first call to `map` would have to return a function and an iterable for the second call to `map` to work. 4. You later call `printt` with no argument when it requires one argument. (...more)

Comment: The problem is that calling `timeout` on a `Future` (or iterating the result of a call to `map` made with a *timeout* argument) throws an exception  if the `Future` has not completed within the time specified, but the task continues to run, i.e. it does *not* stop the running thread. You need to arrange for your function (is it `check_connection`?) to terminate on its own after 60 seconds.

Comment: sorry I want to invoke check_connection not printt if there is a timeout error  I edited it

Comment: @Booboo i want to make the threadpool run in a timer  do you know how can i do that thank you

Comment: If you use class `ThreadPool` from package `multiprocessing.pool`, which supports the same methods as class `Pool` used for multiprocessing but is used for creating a multithreading pool instead, you can call method `terminate` on the pool instance you created and it will terminate all threads and any tasks they are running or queued up for running. You would then have to create a new pool. But there is no way of terminating a specific task. If you create individual `multiprocess.Process` instances, which have more overhead, these can be terminated with method `terminate`.

Comment: @Booboo I want to create something like counter to do something after the time is up and continue doing the loop

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to do. See my first comment I posted. Your nested `map` calls make no sense to me. I see no "loop" so I don't know what your `continue` statement is even supposed to be doing. `printt` doesn't do anything that you have described. I don't know what that "other" function you need to run every minute is. Your best best is to edit your question and describe as fully as possible with as much detail as possible exactly what it is you are attempting to do. As of now I am voting to close this question for lack of details and clarity.

Comment: @Booboo I found a way how to do that with concurrent which is using loop instead of using map and if the time is up it will execute function and it worked great  i don't know how to subclass the map method i will post the answer

Comment: `concurrent.futures` is *not* the package to use. Your program will not terminate until every thread completes regardless of what timeout exception you get. I posted an answer *guessing* what you are trying to do, but I shouldn't have to.

Comment: @Boobo wrapping the threadpool in for loop worked  and no I don't want the thread to terminate I don't know if concurrent is the right package or not but as long it count or time out I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you Boobo for your answer I also come up with another solution which is using submit method in a loop instead of map function  and here is the code

```
import concurrent
import time 

def check_connection():
try:
    request= requests.get("http://google.com",timeout=10)
    print("Connected to the internet")
    pass
except(requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as exception:
    print("No internet connection waiting for connection")
    try:
        request= requests.get("http://google.com",timeout=10)
        print("Connected to the internet")
        pass
    except(requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as exception:
        input("please fix the internet issue to continue")

        
def printt(x): # print output
    print(f'this is number {x}')
    
def counter(x):  
    if time.time() > x:    # if true check connection      
        input('\033[0;37;40mChecking the connection please wait  ...')
        check_connection()
        global t_end
        t_end = time.time() + 10

with open("wordlist.lst", "r") as file:
    passwds_wdlst = file.read().splitlines()

global t_end  # making the variable global
t_end = time.time() + 5  # counter to count here is 5 seconds

for x in range(100000,0,-1): 
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        counter(t_end) #checking if the countdown is finished 
        executor.submit(printt(x))
```

Also, another and better solution is to subclass the map method and embed the timer in it
something like this

```
import concurrent
import time 

class Myconcurrent(concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor):
    def map(self, fn , *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1):
        counter() #checking if the countdown is finished 
#         print("successfully subclassed")
        super().map(fn, *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1)
    
def printt(y , x):
    print(x)
    print(f'tried {y} for username {x}')
    
def counter():
#     print(global_count)
    global t_end
    if time.time() > t_end :            
        input('\033[0;37;40mchanging the ip please wait ...')
#         time.sleep(3)
        t_end = time.time() + global_count
        
def main(count):
    with open("users.lst", "r") as file:
        usrs_wdlst = file.read().splitlines()

    with open("wordlist.lst", "r") as file:
        passwds_wdlst = file.read().splitlines()

    global global_count
    global_count = count

    global t_end
    t_end = time.time() + count 
    
    for user in usrs_wdlst:
        for x in range(100000,0,-1):
            with Myconcurrent() as executor:
#                 counter(t_end) #checking if the countdown is finished 
                executor.map(printt , [str(x)] , [str(user)] )
count=6   
main(count)
```

Comment: I can see that you are not going to re-create a new pool until the previous submitted task ends because, as I have previously commented, tasks submitted continue to run until the end and when you do `with ... as executor:` there is implicit `shutdown(wait=True)` being done at the end of the block waiting for the tasks to end before the block will complete. But you are not submitting task number 2 until task number 1 ends, so you need to reset `t_end` to give it the full 5 seconds. It is also costly creating pools over and over again.

Comment: You would be better off just creating a single thread and timing it. If it takes longer than 5 seconds to complete call, then call `check_connection`. But, of course, you are getting *no concurrency* in either case.

Comment: You should also re-submit the previous task if it times out and your code does not do that.

Comment: i figured out how to subclass the map function and add the counter in it

Comment: Your subclass ignores any *timeout* and *chunksize* arguments that are used with `map` and guarantee that `None` and `1` will be used for these respectively regardless. I doubt that was actually your intention.

Comment: as long it counts down a certain amount of time it's good and that is what i want

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a guess on what you want. This program uses class `ThreadPool` from package `multiprocessing.pool` because, as I commented, you can terminate hanging threads that are taking too long to process by terminating the pool. The program submits individual tasks using method `apply_async`, which returns an `AsyncResult` whose `get` method can be called with a *timeout* argument to get the return value from worker function `printt` or a `TimeOut` exception. For every successful completion, the password is removed from the original set of passwords so what is left are just those passwords for which a timeout occurred. If there are any such passwords, the pool is terminated, `check_connection` is called and we loop back re-submitting tasks just for the passwords that failed on the previous iteration.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool, TimeoutError
import requests
import time

def check_connection():
    try:
        request = requests.get("http://google.com",timeout=10)
        print("Connected to the internet")
    except(requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as exception:
        print("No internet connection waiting for connection")
        try:
            request = requests.get("http://google.com",timeout=10)
            print("Connected to the internet")
        except(requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as exception:
            input("please fix the internet issue to continue")


def printt(x):
    print(x)


TIMEOUT = 60

def main():
    with open(passwd_wdlst, "r") as file:
        passwords = file.read().splitlines()
    MAX_THREADS = 30 # some suitable number
    passwords = set(passwords) # convert to a set
    while passwords: # as long as there are passwords left to processs
        n_threads = min(len(passwords), MAX_THREADS)
        pool = ThreadPool(n_threads)
        # create all the tasks
        results = {pool.apply_async(printt, args=(password,)): password for password in passwords}
        t_end = time.time() + TIMEOUT # everything needs to be done by this time
        for result, password in results.items():
            # wait for completion
            try:
                time_to_wait = max(0, t_end - time.time())
                return_value = result.get(timeout=time_to_wait) # return value from printt, which is None for now
            except TimeoutError:
                pass
            else:
                passwords.remove(password) # successfully completed
        # do we still have any uncompleted passwords?
        if passwords:
            pool.terminate()
            check_connection()

main()
```

Comment: I've updated the code to correct the timeout processing.

Comment: can i make it run in a loop if there is timout error

Comment: There is already a loop, so I don't know what you mean. It may be you are having difficulty in understanding what this code does even with my explanation. See my comment to your answer.